# How to sort a alphanumeric filed in pandas?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I have a dataframe and the first column contains id. How do I sort the first column when it contains alphanumeric data, such as:

```
id = ["6LDFTLL9", "N9RFERBG", "6RHSDD46", "6UVSCF4H", "7SKDEZWE", "5566FT6N","6VPZ4T5P", "EHYXE34N", "6P4EF7BB", "TT56GTN2", "6YYPH399" ]
```

Expected result is

```
id = ["5566FT6N", "6LDFTLL9", "6P4EF7BB", "6RHSDD46", "6UVSCF4H", "6VPZ4T5P", "6YYPH399", "7SKDEZWE", "EHYXE34N", "N9RFERBG", "TT56GTN2" ]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: expected result is    id = ["5566FT6N","6LDFTLL9", "6P4EF7BB", "6RHSDD46", "6UVSCF4H","6VPZ4T5P","6YYPH399","7SKDEZWE", "EHYXE34N",,"N9RFERBG","TT56GTN2" ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the [`.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) method:

```
>>> id.sort()
['5566FT6N', '6LDFTLL9', '6P4EF7BB', '6RHSDD46', '6UVSCF4H', '6VPZ4T5P', '6YYPH399', '7SKDEZWE', 'EHYXE34N', 'N9RFERBG', 'TT56GTN2']
```

This will sort the list in place. If you don't want to change the original `id` list, you can utilize the [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) method

```
>>> sorted(id)
['5566FT6N', '6LDFTLL9', '6P4EF7BB', '6RHSDD46', '6UVSCF4H', '6VPZ4T5P', '6YYPH399', '7SKDEZWE', 'EHYXE34N', 'N9RFERBG', 'TT56GTN2']
>>> id
['6LDFTLL9', 'N9RFERBG', '6RHSDD46', '6UVSCF4H', '7SKDEZWE', '5566FT6N', '6VPZ4T5P', 'EHYXE34N', '6P4EF7BB', 'TT56GTN2', '6YYPH399']
```

Notice, with this one, that `id` is unchanged.

---

For a DataFrame, you want to use [`sort_values()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values).

```
df.sort_values(0, inplace=True)
```

`0` is either the numerical index of your column or you can pass the column name (eg. `id`)

```
           0
5   5566FT6N
0   6LDFTLL9
8   6P4EF7BB
2   6RHSDD46
3   6UVSCF4H
6   6VPZ4T5P
10  6YYPH399
4   7SKDEZWE
7   EHYXE34N
1   N9RFERBG
9   TT56GTN2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i have a dataframe. But the command sorted (df[íd'] ) is not successful

Comment: I've added an example on how to sort the column in a dataframe that should assist you. You will want to use `sort_values()`